# Stackdriver Monitoring Events in Microsoft Teams

Tags: google-cloud-platform, microsoft-teams, stackdriver, google-cloud-stackdriver

We are using Microsoft Teams for communication in our company.

Is there a way to receive Google Stackdriver Notifications there?

Comment: You can build your own [Connector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/connectors/connectors) to push these notifications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google Stackdriver has different Notification option, you can get notified by:

[Email](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/support/notification-options#email) or [Cloud Mobile App](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/support/notification-options#cloud-mobile-app) or [PagerDuty](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/support/notification-options#pagerduty) or with [SMS notifications](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/support/notification-options#sms_notifications) and more...

For More options, See this public [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/support/notification-options)

One of the option that maybe useful in your case is to create a [Webhooks connector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/connectors/connectors-creating), then there is stackdriver notification option for Webhooks, see the [link](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/support/notification-options#webhooks)

Comment: the outgoing webhook of stackdriver and the incomming webhooks connector are not compatible, as they use different formats and in microsoft teams chats/channels do not have an email address (only users do). looks like making a mailing list in office 365 is the best option so far

Comment: then choose email option in stackdriver monitoring and add how many emails for these users in your microsoft teams chats.